# Undefined class constant 'FECTH_ASSOC' , unable to fetch selected row in an associative array

Tags: php, mysql, associative-array

What I want, is to fetch the Selected query in an Associative array.
The Select query works fine but while fetching the query It gives this error:

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'FECTH_ASSOC' in D:\xampp\htdocs\MyWork\admin\workEdit.php:7 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\MyWork\admin\workEdit.php
>   on line 7

Here Are my Code:

connection.php

```
<?php
class Connection{
    static $dbHost ='localhost';
    static $dbName ='db_idream_workschedule';
    static $dbusername ='root';
    static $dbpassword ='';
    static $con;

    static function connect(){
    try{
        self::$con = new PDO("mysql:dbHost=".self::$dbHost.";dbname=".self::$dbName,self::$dbusername,self::$dbpassword);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

    }
}
?>
```

workTable.php

```
<a href="workEdit.php?id=<?php echo $row['jobId']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a> || <a onclick="return confirm('are you sure you want to delete this ?')" href="function.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&image=<?php echo $row['media'];?>&page=deleteUser" > <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
```

This code is to pass the id to another page to edit the data in workEdit.php

workEdit.php

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];    
    require_once('connection.php');
    $dbcon = new Connection();
    $dbcon->connect();
    $result=$dbcon::$con->query("SELECT * FROM `work` WHERE jobId=".$id);
    $data = $result ->fetch(PDO::FECTH_ASSOC);
?>
```

I really don't know what is wrong with this code. I've been using the same code before which worked perfectly fine for me but I have no idea why it's not working.Help would really be appreciated :)

Comment: `FETCH_ASSOC` not `FECTH_ASSOC`!

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a Typo on your part please, check the spelling, it should be

> PDO::FETCH_ASSOC